# Mass Upload of Freight Agreement in SAP TM

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

I need your assistance on how to mass upload freight agreement. Is there any BAPI/Class that I can use to upload the details? And also can we upload freight agreement data using the Excel Integration in the GUI? If so, can you share the steps on how to do it?

Many thanks.